# Jquery post multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, parameters

I am very new to HTML and jQuery (and also AJAX).

I used this code to post 1 object, but I want to post multiple objects (when I click button "submit"(id=analsis) it takes xyz object id's content and posts it to `127.0.0.1:5002`).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#analysis').bind('click', function() {
    $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5002/', {
      contract: $('textarea[name="text"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      var parsed = JSON.parse(data)
      $("#xyz").text(parsed['abc']);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

My form looks like this and (also has 6 dropdowns):

[image]

So I want to post all of them to `http://127.0.0.1:5002/`.

Comment: you can just submit the form. look also at https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ if this is more in the direction of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code doesn't quite do what you described: instead of posting xyz's value it looks up a textarea with name="text" and posts its value to the server. The server result is parsed as json and one of the result properties ("abc") is assigned to your "xyz" (form) element.

You could do the same thing for multiple values adding properties to the object in the second post parameter:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#analysis').bind('click', function() { 
        $.post(
            'http://127.0.0.1:5002/',
            { 
                'contract': $('textarea[name="text"]').val(),
                'slider1':  $('#slider1').val(),
                'slider2':  $('#slider2').val(),
                'slider3':  $('#slider3').val(),
                'slider4':  $('#slider4').val(),
                'dropdown1':  $('#dropdown1').val(),
                'dropdown2':  $('#dropdown2').val(),
                'dropdown3':  $('#dropdown3').val(),
                'dropdown4':  $('#dropdown4').val(),
                'dropdown5':  $('#dropdown5').val(),
                'dropdown6':  $('#dropdown6').val(),

            },
            function(data) { 
                var parsed = JSON.parse(data);                  
                $("#xyz").text(parsed['abc']); 
            }); 
         return false; 
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: Do i always need to tag this data xyz, or lets say can i associate this data with "#analysis' - the button

Comment: Try this code///

var parsed = JSON.parse(data); $("#xyz").text(parsed.abc);

Comment: Im sorry but i am bit confused- I want to send this file as 1json object -  "xyz" is the container which has all the filters (not the text box anymore), Any suggestions?

<script>
 $(function() {$('#analysis').bind('click', function() {
   $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5002/',{
     'CK': $('CK').val(),
     'OCE': $('OCE').val(),
     'SR': $('SR').val(),
     'range_01': $('range_01').val(),
    },
   function(data) {
                 var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                 $("#xyz").text(parsed['abc']);
             });
            return false;
     });
   });
</script>

Comment: Not sure what is the difference to the previous code (still looks like you're posting form values and parsing part of the result into your `xyz`form field), but to start with most jquery selectors in your example are missing the `#` prefix.